# No puedo recuperar información de base de datos Firebase en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

estoy tratando de obtener un String o cualquier tipo de objeto de mi nodo Users de mi base de datos y en si puedo enviar y actualizar data pero no puedo recuperar nada pues cuando debugueo no entra a mi método desde la parte donde lo invoco:

```
mensajeRef.child("krizdevil").child("Username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() en adelante
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mensajeRef = ref.child("Users");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
 }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mensajeRef.child("krizdevil").child("Username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
  }
```

[image: Esquema de mi base de datos:]

Mi esquema de la base de datos es esta:

Comment: ¿Probaste poner un `breakpoint` en tu onDataChange, cambiando el valor del campo `Username` de manera manual en la consola de Firebase y aún así no se dispara?. Si ese es el caso, entonces el problema podría estar en las reglas definidas de Firebase. Al acceder a la base de datos en la consola de Firebase, hay una pestaña llamada `Rules` o `Reglas`, ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y adjuntar dichas reglas?.

Answer (score 0):

prueba a hacer el código de esta manera, igual es la forma en la que lo estás realizando aunque a simple vista no veo ningún error grave.
Ten en cuenta también que las reglas de Firebase deben estar puestas para que en la lectura no necesites estar logueado, lo puedes mirar dentro del panel de firebase database en la pestaña de rules.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference mensajeRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     mensajeRef = database.getReference("Users");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mensajeRef.child("krizdevil").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Username").getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Gracias probe y no obtuve nada, el problema está en que cuando debugueo ni siquiera me toma en cuenta el metodo addValueEventListener y se salta hasta el final; en el tema de permisos los habilite todos. Lo que tal vez piense es que estoy usando una versión gratis y creo que esta es solo por un mes, tal vez pruebe la de paga para ver si así puedo consumir data o sino comenzar un proyecto nuevo, igual es solo con caracter didactico esto.

Comment: Yo utilizo firebase gratis en una de mis aplicaciones y tiene más de 6000 descargas, no es problema de firebase, será problema de la versión de SDK o permisos, si eres tan amable comparte una imagen de la página de "Rules" de firebase Database a ver si te podemos ayudar.